# How to get the border pixels or erased area in an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision

Imagine I have the following image with an erased area, now I want to know the border pixels of this area, how can I achieve it in Python?
[The image with one area being erased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKTss.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Emm i`ll just put down the code without running, you can try it later on yourself.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('you_input_image.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# assume the while area 255.255.255 are what you put manually and you want it removed. 
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 254, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# There might be multiple are with 255. then you need to find the index of the largest contour
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt=contours[max_index]
print cnt
# cnt contains all the point in this largest contour
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use opencv to do this. The main function to use is `cv2.findContours`

Drawing the border in red below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('uKTss.jpg')
gray = rgb2gray(im)

contours = cv2.findContours(gray.astype(np.uint8),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]

for contour in contours:  
    cv2.drawContours(im, contour, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]